# I'm trying to create a submacro as autokeys macro in ms access using numbers in the numpad of the keyboard

Tags: vba

i have created an auto keys macro with different keys like F1 and A, but i want to use the numbers in the numpad and i don't know how to do it. Please can anybody help me...